# How to prevent jquery mobile to apply round corner to icon images in inset list?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

How to prevent jquery mobile to apply round corner to icon images in inset list?

I check this page list with flags http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/lists/lists-inset.html it shows fine but when i'm using the same icons are having round corner.

```
<li data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-li-has-icon ui-corner-top">
<div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
    <div class="ui-btn-text">
        <a data-transition="slide" href="lists.html" class="ui-link-inherit"><img class="ui-li-icon ui-li-thumb ui-corner-tl" alt="France" src="http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/book_addresses.png">Lists</a>
    </div>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"></span>
</div>
</li>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQM has another class for this:

- ui-corner-none

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/TVydA/9/

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" class="type-home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/book_addresses.png" alt="lists" class="ui-li-icon">Lists (class="ui-li-icon")</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/book_addresses.png" alt="lists" class="ui-li-icon">Lists (class="ui-li-icon")</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <br />

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/book_addresses.png" alt="lists" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none">Lists (class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none")</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/book_addresses.png" alt="lists" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none">Lists (class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none")</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Looking over the jQM CSS

- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.css

I see it's very close to what @naugtur suggested

```
.ui-corner-none {
    -moz-border-radius:     0;
    -webkit-border-radius:  0;
    border-radius:          0;
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to disable the corner for other elements so html class is better then editing the css.

Comment: it's always a good idea to use the tools (code) jQM provides, glad to help

Answer (score 4):

You should override the CSS rather than loop over every element. This won't work on element that are brought to DOM later.

try

```
<style>
img.ui-corner-tl{
-webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
 border-radius: 0px !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have "ui-corner-tl" in your markup for img tag. Did you notice that?

Comment: that's why i asked this question